# How to realise the symbol check in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

How to realise the symbol check in JTextField? I want to see in my `JTextField` only digits. What I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or a [DocumentFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Answer (score 4):

**NumberOnlyFilter.java:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class NumberOnlyFilter extends DocumentFilter
{

    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
        sb.insert(offset, text);
        if(!containsOnlyNumbers(sb.toString())) return;
        fb.insertString(offset, text, attr);
    }
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
        sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
        if(!containsOnlyNumbers(sb.toString())) return;
        fb.replace(offset, length, text, attr);
    }

    /**
     * This method checks if a String contains only numbers
     */
    public boolean containsOnlyNumbers(String text)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        boolean isMatch = matcher.matches();
        return isMatch;
    }

}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
((AbstractDocument)yourTxtField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumberOnlyFilter());
```